# Dog all of a sudden scared of living room wall

Tags: dogs, behavior, training, fear

My dog is a rescue. She has a very skittish, submissive personality--she gets scared by things fairly easily, but usually I can at least figure out why. But recently she has been avoiding coming into the living room towards the outside wall (I am in a small above ground apartment). I'm gone all day at work, and if I had to guess why she is all of a sudden scared, it would be because a bird flew into the window, or maintenance maybe was doing some work on the roof against that wall. It's unclear exactly what she's scared of, but she hesitates when coming into the room, looking in the general direction of the windows/wall (not always in the exact same spot), and then decides to turn around and run back into the bedroom.

What is the best way to get her to go back to not having a fear of the wall?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct something about the wall scares her. Since you were not home when the scary event happened and unless it happens again when you are home, you may never know the cause. Part of the fear is separation anxiety. She still is not conformable that you will come back. Separation anxiety is hard to cure and there is no best way. With regard to the wall you need to spend time by the wall by yourself and continue to call her to you. I promise it won't happen fast, but she will eventually come to you at the wall. At first she will be very scared, but with time her love of you will be more than her fear. I don't know if she will get over the fear of the wall, but she will deal with it when you are home.

In my opinion, the separation anxiety is the leading cause of her fear. When you are home she will start to be comfortable. This is if you have a regular schedule. An irregular schedule is a different story.